# Magento 2.2.5: Error when trying to Override Widget

Tags: overrides, magento-2.2.5, widget

I'm doing override widget to my custom module.

So everything was great in the backend, until i come to the frontend and see nothing at all.

I mean it works perfect in backend, but not with the frontend.

I'm following CatalogWidget.

So here is my custom module, check it out:

[image]

Its under namespace `Gssi`.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\bezdan\app\code\Gssi\ProductsSlider\Block\Product\ProductsList.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Gssi\ProductsSlider\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList as CatalogWidgetProductList;

/**
 * Catalog Products List widget block
 * Class ProductsList
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class ProductsList extends CatalogWidgetProductList implements BlockInterface, IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Name of request parameter for page number value
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const PAGE_VAR_NAME = 'np';

    /**
     * Default value for products per page
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 5;

    /**
     * Default value whether show pager or not
     */
    const DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER = false;

    /**
     * Instance of pager block
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\Html\Pager
     */
    protected $pager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder
     */
    protected $sqlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule
     */
    protected $rule;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions
     */
    protected $conditionsHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder $sqlBuilder
     * @param \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule $rule
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder $sqlBuilder,
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule $rule,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $productCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $httpContext,
            $sqlBuilder,
            $rule,
            $conditionsHelper
        );
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

As i said, i'm following CatalogWidget module, so this block `ProductsList.php` is extends from it ( I'm not sure if i need to call every function in that `ProductList.php` and use `parent::_FunctionName` or they just called themselves.).

> C:\xampp\htdocs\bezdan\app\code\Gssi\ProductsSlider\etc\widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="products_list" class="Gssi\ProductsSlider\Block\Product\ProductsList" is_email_compatible="true"
            placeholder_image="Magento_CatalogWidget::images/products_list.png" ttl="86400">
        <label translate="true">Catalog Products List</label>
        <description translate="true">List of Products</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="show_pager" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
                       source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Display Page Control</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_per_page" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products per Page</label>
                <depends>
                    <parameter name="show_pager" value="1" />
                </depends>
                <value>5</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="products_count" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Number of Products to Display</label>
                <value>10</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Template</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="default" value="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
                        <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
                    </option>
                    <option name="slider" value="product/widget/content/slider.phtml">
                        <label translate="true">Products Slider</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="text" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Cache Lifetime (Seconds)</label>
                <description translate="true">86400 by default, if not set. To refresh instantly, clear the Blocks HTML Output cache.</description>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="condition" xsi:type="conditions" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10"
                       class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\Widget\Conditions">
                <label translate="true">Conditions</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
        <containers>
            <container name="content">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.top">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
            <container name="content.bottom">
                <template name="grid" value="default" />
            </container>
        </containers>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

The diffrence between my widget custom module and the widget of `Catalog Widget` module is i put 1 more `<option>` in the `<parameter name="template">`.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\bezdan\app\code\Gssi\ProductsSlider\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="Gssi\ProductsSlider\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

In here, slider.phtml and grid.phtml is the same, and also, i copy it from `C:\xampp\htdocs\bezdan\vendor\magento\module-catalog-widget\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\content\grid.phtml`

So i will not post grid.phtml here.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\bezdan\app\code\Gssi\ProductsSlider\view\frontend\templates\product\widget\content\slider.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
echo 'dsadsdsdsadsdsa';
/**
 * Template for displaying products list widget
 *
 * @var $block \Gssi\ProductsSlider\Block\Product\ProductsList
 */
?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())):?>
<?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';

    $mode = 'grid';

    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $title = $block->getTitle() ? __($block->getTitle()) : '';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::DEFAULT_VIEW;
    $description = false;
?>
    <div class="block widget block-products-list <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
        <?php if ($title):?>
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $title; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $mode; ?>">
                <ol class="product-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $type; ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                <?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"
                                       class="product-item-link">
                                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php
                                echo $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type);
                                ?>

                                <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                    <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}'
                                                                type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                        ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary"
                                                                data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'
                                                                type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                                    <a href="#"
                                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item); ?>'
                                                       class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare): ?>
                                                    <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');?>
                                                    <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item);?>'
                                                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo($iterator == count($items)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

The important thing is it seem like not running into the slider.phtml, because i've put `echo "dsadsdsdsadsdsa"` in the code, but it doesn't show up. So i dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove etc\di.xml as you do not need the preference and change your reference to the new template to include the new module's name.

app/code/Gssi/ProductsSlider/etc/widget.xml:39

```
<option name="slider" value="Gssi_ProductsSlider::product/widget/content/slider.phtml">
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but if i need that to custom something new? I still need etc/di.xml right? And is that di.xml causing my issue?

Comment: The preference in di.xml is causing issues in your code. Once it's removed and you make the change I suggested it will start working.

Comment: Hmmm .. so may you explain why that preference causing issue in my code please? I dont understand at all .. :'(

Comment: I'm not sure but I was getting an empty output same as you until I removed it. It may be that you are already referencing the new class in widget.xml.

Comment: Hmmm .. this is weird, because if i need to custom a new block, so i will need to call preference  right? So how could this be issue? :)

Comment: Ok I figured it out, you're fine using a preference but it's the __construct function within your new block file which was causing it to break. __construct function can either be removed or you need to fix the data that is being passed to the parent constructor function as it doesn't match what it's expecting.

Comment: i though that __construct() with 2 "_" , cant be remove?

Comment: Oh i figure it out why , its because i wasn't pass the $data, which is an empty array in the __construct() function, Thanks for helping me :) you got +1 and accepted answer  from me :)